# Display Zend_Form form errors in ViewScript

Tags: zend-framework, forms

I'm trying to display all form errors before the form using a ViewScript. Here is the code that I'm currently trying to use within my ViewScript:

```
<div class="errors">
<?php echo $this->formErrors($this->element->getMessages()); ?>
</div>
```

This call gives me an error message:

> Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I've seen this same code suggested other places but its not working for me. If I print out $this->element->getMessages() I do see the error messages as the following:

> Array ( [myField] => Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) )

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The getMessages() returns an array of form element names as keys which each contain an array of errors for that element. So basically instead of handing the formErrors view helper:

```
Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty )
```

You are handing it:

```
Array ( [myField] => Array ( [isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty ) )
```

You would want to do something like this instead:

```
$arrMessages = $this->myForm->getMessages();
foreach($arrMessages as $field => $arrErrors) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<ul><li>%s</li>%s</ul>',
        $this->myForm->getElement($field)->getLabel(),
        $this->formErrors($arrErrors)

    );
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar but I like your solution better. Odd that there is no function available to handle all form errors together like this, only to handle them for one field at a time.

Answer (score -1):

As [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139812/mark) points out in his answer, the getMessages() returns an array of form element names as keys which each contain an array of errors for that element; and his solution is:

```
$arrMessages = $this->myForm->getMessages();
foreach($arrMessages as $field => $arrErrors) {
    echo sprintf(
        '<ul><li>%s</li>%s</ul>',
        $this->myForm->getElement($field)->getLabel(),
        $this->formErrors($arrErrors)

    );
}
```

This works, as long as `getMessages()` results in a two-dimensional array.  However, if the form is based on relational data sets generated by Doctrine (or some other plugin), the error message associated with a field might also be an array and the above code will crash because it treats `$arrErrors` as a string when it turns out to be an array.

To capture the error messages if there's a second data set we could introduce a foreach statement nested inside the first foreach statement, but that won't work when `getMessages()` results in a two-dimensional array; nor does it work if the data sets are more than two-deep.

In a relational data scenario where we don't know how deep the error message comes from, a scalable solution is

```
$arrMessages = $this->myForm->getMessages();
print_r ($arrMessages);
```